# angular scroll into view moves the full page

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using scrollIntoView for scrolling my view, but it moves to top the full page some pixels, it's such of simple code:

```
  scroll() {
      //moves the full view
      this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
      //does nothing
      // this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.scrollTop = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop - this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.offsetTop
```

}

how can I do for solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't related to Angular but hope this helps.

scrollIntoView() defaults to alignToTop and accepts boolean/object to control that.

try using this -

> this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(false);

OR

> this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({block: "end"});

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Let me know, if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following workaround to move the window scroll after calling scrollIntoView:

```
this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
if (window.scrollY !== 0) {
   window.scrollBy(0, -window.scrollY);
}
```